# Can I force C#/.NET to use the newest version of assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, reload

While working on tAPI (a Terraria (if you don't know the game, just look it up, it's awesome) modding API), we hit a problem with cross-mod code references. Basically, you can call methods from the other mod (as long as you tell the mod builder to add references to that mod obviously), but the moment you try to reload the mods, you can't really be sure stuff will work: if you reference any class from the other mod, it will always use the FIRST version the game loaded, not the latest. That means you can't call anything static or instantiate the classes from the other mod, which is a real problem when you're working on some kind of an API mod.

The mods themselves are standard C# code, with some extra JSON data we parse.

I tried doing the same thing outside of the tAPI source code, here is my take at it (long code, told pastebin.com to never expire the paste though): http://pastebin.com/hjY57xJh

It has exactly the same problem though. The second time the static method is called, it should print "456", not "123" like it does.

So, my question is: can I do anything to actually force the game to use the latest assembly and not the first one?

We thought about using AppDomains, but they're a pain to implement and as I understand it, they work by serializing the data going through, which might make the game plainly unplayable due to the amount of calls it has to do to the mods.

EDIT: I don't really mind the fact, that the assembly still uses up memory after "reloading" mods. I just want the new assembly after the "reload" to take priority over the old one.

Comment: You likely looking for [assembly redirect](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+assembly+redirect+config) if you have strongly singed asemblies. You also may want to read on loading assemblies and context/versions - [Suzanne Cook's blog](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+assembly+load+suzanne+cook) is a good start. Multiple AppDomains are unlikely answer as most API don't work well accross such boundary.

Comment: Assembly redirecting seems to be a feature available only before the actual app gets executed, I don't think there's a way to actually use it while the app is already running.

Comment: First half of the question now (load multiple versions of the same assemblies into single AppDomain) is duplicate of many similar posts on SO (search); the second half (re-point parent API to new assembly) requires more details, most obvious implementation is custom version-aware proxy that will on one side work with the API and on other side bind to whatever version of your assembly you want.

Comment: Since I still hadn't updated my answer and was unlikely to figure out an improvement in the near future, I've deleted it for now. Hopefully, the fact that your question now shows no answers will attract the attention of others who can be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I totally forgot about this question, but: in the end we kinda ignored the problem. tAPI mods now either extend ModBase or APIModBase. If you're using the latter, the game will never really try to even reload the mod (assembly) - it will just stay the same after the first load, until you restart the game. It's a little annoying for modders, but there isn't much that can be done about this fact. At least all the content mods that only depend on API mods can be freely reloaded without causing any problems.